# Asymptotic integral with bessel function

Tags: asymptotics, contour-integration, bessel-functions

I would like to study the large $t\gg 1$ behavior of this integral in the complex plane
$$
\oint_{|w|=1} dw\frac{(1+w)^{\eta t}}{w^{t+3/2}}I_1(2t\sqrt{w})
$$
for $\eta>1$

Comment: And how's the progress?